# Flag declined and info shows wrong information?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

Today i looked at my "helpful flags" and I have seen that one flag has been declined. The flag was an "other" flag under a question, where i wrote:

> "The question does not contain the necessary informations. At least an error log should be added to be able to help".

I also wrote a comment under the question to let the user know that. Now the decline info:

> "declined - Then use a standard close vote or flag, and leave them a comment to that effect.".

The info suggests 3 things i can do:

1. close-vote: I can't, not enough reputation.
2. Leave a comment: I did, but i thought the question should be closed until he gives enough information, so that he remembers that in future.
3. Flag: That's what makes me think. I flagged the question. This flag was declined and the info says "use a flag". It sounds strange to me to decline a flag and suggest to use a flag instead...

So my question is: Did i misunderstand the info? If yes what should i have done instead of flagging?

Comment: "Other" flags are handled by (and visible to) diamond moderators *only.* "Close" flags are handled by the community.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should have flagged, but used the standard "close" reasons rather than the custom "other" reason.

Moderators are not here to close questions - except in rare circumstances.

If you "flag to close" then the question will appear on the close review queue where 3k+ users can review it and vote appropriately. For the most part 3K+ users do a great job of closing questions that need closing without moderators getting involved.

Comment: Ah okay so i should have used the "close for other reason" flag instead of the "other" flag. For what should i use the "other" flag?

Comment: @Springrbua "Other" is for something that needs a diamond moderator's attention, but for which there is no other valid flagging/voting option.

Comment: @Springrbua - for something that regular users can't handle.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. I must have missed the "close for other reason" flag...